# Read an input file one line at a time to pass as input to grep

Tags: linux, command-line, command-line-arguments

My requirement is to read a file and then run a grep command on the read line one at a time for all the lines in the file.

Filtering the required file which matches a pattern

```
find . -name *.ini -exec grep -w HTC {} \; -print | grep ini > input.files
```

cat input.files

```
./PLATFORM/android/build/integration/android/suites/android_Prefs_Devices_Comms_Suite/ini/android_0019.ini
./PLATFORM/android/build/integration/android/suites/android_Prefs_Devices_Comms_Suite/ini/android_0150.ini
./PLATFORM/android/build/integration/android/suites/android_Prefs_Devices_Comms_Suite/ini/android_0616_1.ini
./PLATFORM/android/build/integration/android/suites/android_SI_Query_Suite/ini/android_0547_4.ini
./PLATFORM/android/build/integration/android/suites/android_SI_Query_Suite/ini/android_0578.ini
./PLATFORM/android/build/integration/android/suites/android_PDL_Suite/ini/android_5203_1.ini
./PLATFORM/android/build/integration/android/suites/android_System_Maintenance_Suite/ini/android_0579_2.ini
```

Any idea how to read one line at a time from input.files and execute a grep command on that ?

```
cat input.files -exec grep -w HTC_One {} \;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There won't be any difference in the result if you say:

```
grep pattern file1
grep pattern file2
```

or

```
grep pattern file1 file2
```

Simply, use `xargs`:

```
cat input.files | xargs grep -w HTC_One
```

Answer (score 0):

Use xargs instead:

`cat input.files | xargs grep -w HTC_One {} \;`

From the xargs man page:

> xargs reads items
>          from  the  standard  input, delimited by blanks (which can be protected
>          with double or single quotes or a backslash) or newlines, and  executes
>          the  command (default is /bin/echo) one or more times with any initial-
>          arguments followed by items read from standard input.